# Laravel Forge Mail Error Connection can't be established with host mailhog

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun, mailhog

I have very strange error on my Laravel Forge production server.

My .env config and mail.php config variables:

```
smtp.mailgun.org
587
<mailgun username>
<mailgun server>

smtp
smtp.mailgun.org
<mailgun username>
<mailgun server>
```

I just dumped this by "echo" on the server, so the server definitely sees the config and env's variables as mailgun.
But when I trying to send email through Mail::to function, I had this error:

```
[2021-09-25 21:20:29] production.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known at /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:261)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->{closure}()
#1 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(264): stream_socket_client()
#2 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(58): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->establishSocketConnection()
#3 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(143): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize()
#4 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(65): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#5 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(521): Swift_Mailer->send()
#6 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(288): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage()
#7 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php(187): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->send()
#8 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Localizable.php(19): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable->Illuminate\\Mail\\{closure}()
#9 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php(188): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable->withLocale()
#10 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/SendQueuedMailable.php(65): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable->send()
#11 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Mail\\SendQueuedMailable->handle()
#12 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#13 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#14 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#15 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#16 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#17 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}()
#18 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#19 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#20 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(120): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow()
#21 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}()
#22 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#23 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(122): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#24 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(70): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware()
#25 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(98): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->call()
#26 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(428): Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->fire()
#27 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(378): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process()
#28 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(329): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob()
#29 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(117): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runNextJob()
#30 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker()
#31 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#32 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#33 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#34 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#35 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#36 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#37 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#38 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#39 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#40 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#41 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#42 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(92): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#43 /home/forge/maxion.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#44 /home/forge/maxion.io/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#45 {main}
"}
```

For some reason, in the error message, we could see "mailhog" variable. I searched a lot, and couldn't find anything like mailhog in my project. Everywhere var is Mailgun.
Also on the localhost, I don't have any troubles with email sending, it's the only problem on Namecheap VPS and Laravel Forge control panel.
I have written to the Namecheap support, they see nothing blocks outcoming requests, so ports must be opened from their side.

Also, here is telnet output:

```
Trying 3.93.221.84...
Connected to smtp.mailgun.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I tried a lot of things but never came to success. I think the clue is the mailhog variable, it is not clear how exactly on the server it gets inside the Laravel mail functions, and why this happens only in production.
I would be very glad to any guesses since I ran out of my ideas)

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel project directory, edit config/mail.php and add the following:

```
'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ]
```

And run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Disabling verficiation and allowing self signed certificates is a huge security risk. It's also unnecessary, because Mailgun does not use self signed certificates.